# Definir ordem de scripts de inicialização

Tags: sistema-operacional, scripting

Utilizo o So Linux Ubuntu desde de a versão 7.04, porém já usei outras distros antes, e percebo que a cada versão algo muda de maneira inexplicável, coisas que muitas vezes atrapalham bastante. O meu problema é o seguinte, tenho alguns servidores com a versão server 8.04lts, e na inicialização deles eu setava no rc.local um script que fazia alguns testes e mostravam o resultado antes de apresentar a tela de login, o mesmo ficava na tela, ex., testes de conexão de internet e outros, em caso de problema o usuário olhava a tela do servidor ao ligar e veria que ao iniciar algo errado aconteceu, isso funcionava perfeitamente bem, pois na ordem do boot da versão citada o rc.local era o último arquivo do boot a ser executado, porém com da versão 12.04 para frente isso mudou, o rc.local é executado na metade do processo, sendo assim o resultado do meu script passa rápido e n fica na tela, deste jeito não fica nada funcional para mim, gostaria de saber como fazer o rc.local ser o último a ser executado na inicialização do So Linux ubuntu Server 14.04lts. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Para quem está votando para fechar, peço que comente o motivo. Essa pergunta não é nada ampla, na realidade é bem direta: como fazer com que um script execute por último no boot do ubuntu.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, ele quer executar o script num determinado perído. (Após todo o restante do processo ocorrer), porém definir a ordem dos scripts dum `Sistema GNU/Linux` (*a pergunta/título*) é algo extremamente abrangente na minha opinião e por isso votei para fechar.

Comment: Só para tentar ajudar, acredito que esses links serão bastante úteis: [man boot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/boot.7.html) e o organizador de boot [insserv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/insserv.8.html). Novamente: explicar ambos me parece bastante amplo para uma pergunta neste estilo QA/PR.

Comment: Realmente é uma pergunta direta, mas como poderia ser interpretada de várias formas, como vem acontecendo, tive que contar uma historinha antes de ir direto ao assunto, mas realmente como falaram e diga-se de passagem um resumo ótimo, o que quero é: "fazer um script executar por último no boot do ubuntu 14.04lts server". Obrig pelas respostas...